# Is a textarea the most appropriate UI element to show/hide link text like in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, textarea

I need to show a link on my page and I'm looking for examples of how to do it well.

I looked at Google Maps and it seems like they display the link in a **textarea inside a show/hide span**:

For example, if you go to a Google Maps address, on the far top right of the map there is a hyperlink called "Link" and when you click it, a small overlay pops up over the map.

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Cupertino,+CA,+United+States&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=35.547176,55.634766&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Cupertino,+Santa+Clara,+California&ll=37.355422,-122.032013&spn=0.139453,0.217323&z=12

The **textarea** seems to be a *good option here because their links are very long*.

**Is that the best UI element for this case?**

Another option is to pop it up into a `jQuery UI overlay` and simply display the whole thing as text.

Would appreciate any pointers on where to look for this.

Answer (score 0):

My vote goes for textbox (`<input type="text />`) because it's easy to implement so that the  links is selected when you enter the box. This makes it easy for the user to copy the link.

Comment: This technique has frustrated me, because many places (Skitch used to be the big offender) use an input but DON'T select on focus, so you're not sure if you've selected everything, and can't see if you have.